# jqGrid custom onCellSelect not firing beforeSaveCell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am writing some piece of code inside **onCellSelect**, which executes fine

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
        if (iCol > 0) {
            $("#gridMain_d").jqGrid("resetSelection");
            $("#gridMain_d").setSelection(rowid, true);
        }
    }
```

But the problem is because of this code **beforeSaveCell** event is not firing. I know this because as soon as I remove this code beforeSaveCell starts working. i have tried using return statement but nothing works.

**UPDATE**
I commented the code written above and added this code

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        var $self = $(this), iCol, cm,
            $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
            $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow"),
            p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");

        if ($(e.target).is("input[type=checkbox]") && $td.length > 0) {
            $self.jqGrid("setSelection", $tr.attr("id"), true, e);
        }
        else {
            $self.jqGrid('resetSelection');
            $self.jqGrid("setSelection", $tr.attr("id"), true, e);
        }
        return true;
    },
```

But still **beforeSaveCell** event is not firing.

**UPDATE 2**
This jsFiddle replicates the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/eranjali08/CzVVK/1175/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many callbacks which depends from each other. Moreover it could be difference of such dependencies in different versions of jqGrid. I recommend you to use `beforeSelectRow` instead of `onCellSelect` because it will be the first callback which will be called on click on the cell of jqGrid. All information which you could need you can get from the second parameter (`e` in the code below) of `beforeSelectRow`:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td");
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest($td[0]),
        colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        columnName = colModel[i].name;
    //...
    // one can use here $td.html(), $td.text() to access the content of the cell
    // columnName is the name of the column which cell was clicked
    // iCol - the index of the column which cell was clicked
    return true; // or false to suppress the selection
}
```

You need just don't forget that `beforeSelectRow` should return the value which inform jqGrid whether to select the clicked row or not. The values `false` or `"stop"` returned from `beforeSelectRow` suppresses the selection of the clicked row. All other values allows the selection.

**UPDATED**: I analysed your code one more time and I hope I've found the reason of your problem. You use `resetSelection` which is evil in case of usage of cell editing. Look at [the last line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L3197) of `resetSelection`.

```
t.p.savedRow = [];
```

It **destroys** the array holding the information about the currently editing cell. So the cell can't be saved or restored more.

To solve the problem you have to remove `resetSelection` from your code. If you really need to use `resetSelection` you should replace it for example to the loop with call of `setSelection`. The corresponding code could look close to the code below:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this), iCol, cm, i, idsOfSelectedRows,
        $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
        $tr = $td.closest("tr.jqgrow"),
        p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");

    if ($(e.target).is("input[type=checkbox]") && $td.length > 0) {
        $self.jqGrid("setSelection", $tr.attr("id"), true, e);
    }
    else {
        //$self.jqGrid('resetSelection');
        idsOfSelectedRows = p.selarrrow.slice(0); // make copy of the array
        for (i = 0; i < idsOfSelectedRows.length; i++) {
            $self.jqGrid("setSelection", idsOfSelectedRows[i], false, e);
        }
        $self.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid, false, e);
    }
    return false;
},
```

Comment: @eranjali08: Could you provide small demo with the description of the test case which reproduces the problem?

Comment: @eranjali08: See **UPDATED** part of my answer and modified version of the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/CzVVK/1176/

Comment: It works like a charm. Cann't thank you enough @Oleg :)